# reading latex accents of .bib in R

Tags: r, latex, bibtex

When I export .bib references with accents coded in latex (as they are exported from mendeley, for example), then they don't look as expected for further independent processing in R.

myfile.bib:

```
@misc{Llorens1980,
abstract = {Aunque el reactor de fusi{\'{o}}n termonuclear constituye la esperanza m{\'{a}}s s{\'{o}}lida de obtenci{\'{o}}n de energ{\'{i}}a a gran escala, los problemas f{\'{i}}sicos y tecnol{\'{o}}gicos que el mismo plantea son muchos y dif{\'{i}}ciles.},
author = {Llorens, Mart{\'{i}}n and Menzell, Alfred and Villarrubia, Miguel},
booktitle = {Investigaci{\'{o}}n y Ciencia (Scientific American)},
keywords = {INGENIER{\'{I}}A NUCLEAR},
number = {51},
pages = {1--5},
title = {{F{\'{i}}sica y tecnolog{\'{i}}a del reactor de fusi{\'{o}}n}},
volume = {DICIEMBRE},
year = {1980}
}
```

In R:

```
testbibR <- RefManageR::ReadBib("myfile.bib")
testbibR$author
[1] "Mart\\'in Llorens"  "Alfred Menzell"     "Miguel Villarrubia"
testbibR$title
[1] "{F{\\'{i}}sica y tecnolog{\\'{i}}a del reactor de fusi{\\'{o}}n}"

btex<-bibtex::read.bib("myfile.bib")
btex$author
[1] "Mart\\'in Llorens"  "Alfred Menzell"     "Miguel Villarrubia"
btex$title
[1] "{F{\\'{i}}sica y tecnolog{\\'{i}}a del reactor de fusi{\\'{o}}n}"

testbib <- bib2df::bib2df("myfile.bib")
testbib$AUTHOR[[1]]
[1] "Llorens, Mart{\\'{i}}n" "Menzell, Alfred"        "Villarrubia, Miguel"   
testbib$TITLE
[1] "F{\\'{i}}sica y tecnolog{\\'{i}}a del reactor de fusi{\\'{o}}n"
```

I wonder if I can see a `Martín` in those places

Related post: https://github.com/ropensci/bib2df/issues/35

By the way, when importing / exporting those bibs, packages seem to rewrite in (other) latex format, the author field (`Mart\'in`). Only `bib2df` writes all fields as the original, see above.

```
RefManageR::WriteBib(testbibR,"refmanager.bib")

bibtex::write.bib(btex,"bibtex.bib")

bib2df::df2bib(testbib,"bib2df")
```

Comment: I am not familiar with any TeX to Unicode converters for R. You may have to just do a manual string replace for unicode characters you care about.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to remove some latex accents from .bib.

As I based this answer in this [post' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580132/6388753), the first part is in python.

#### python: Dictionary to .csv

```
latexAccents = [
    [ u"Í", "{\\'{I}}"],
    [ u"í", "{\\'{i}}"],
    [ u"á", "{\\'{a}}"],
    [ u"é", "{\\'{e}}"],
    [ u"ó", "{\\'{o}}"],
    [ u"ú", "{\\'{u}}"],
    ]

import pandas

mydf = pandas.DataFrame(latexAccents)
newname = "dictaccent.csv"
mydf.to_csv(newname, index =False)
```

#### R: Replace latex in .bib

```
dictaccent <- read.csv("dictaccent.csv")
bibLines   <- readLines("myfile.bib")

library(stringi)

for (i in 1:nrow(dictaccent)){
    for (j in 1:length(bibLines)) {
        bibLines[j]<-stri_replace_all_fixed(bibLines[j], dictaccent$X1[i], dictaccent$X0[i])
    }
}

writeLines(bibLines,"noLatex.bib")
```

[commented in other post](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarkgrubb/latex-input/master/latex.el)